# How can I delete all texts in my data using dplyr?

Tags: r, text, dplyr, tidyverse

If my data looks like this:

```
q2_3  q2_4  q2_5
<chr> <chr> <chr>
1    1A    2B   3C
2    4D    5E   6F
```

---

How can I delete only texts?

I want only numbers to remain!

Comment: What do you mean with "text"? Delete all chr- entries, or keep only the numbers in your columns? Please show your expected outcome.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply! Yes, I meant by having only numbers to remain.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove all the characters which are not digits using `\\D`.

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_all(~gsub('\\D', '', .))

#  q2_3 q2_4 q2_5
#1    1    2    3
#2    4    5    6
```

Or in base R :

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub('\\D', '', x))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(q2_3 = c("1A", "4D"), q2_4 = c("2B", "5E"), q2_5 = c("3C", 
"6F")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I am curious how can I remove only "character" (such as A, B, C) for bunch of data. The data above have only 6 variables so I can remove characters manually. But if I have millions of it, can I use any functions?

Comment: @AaronSu If you want to remove only A, B and C characters you can do `df %>% mutate_all(~gsub('[ABC]', '', .))` . Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use **parse_number()** from readr package (which will extract first number from values):

```
library(readr)

data <- data.frame(q2_3 = c("1A", "4D"), 
                   q2_4 = c("2B", "5E"), 
                   q2_5 = c("3C", "6F"))

data[] <- lapply(data, parse_number)
```

results in

```
> print(data)
  q2_3 q2_4 q2_5
1    1    2    3
2    4    5    6
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! What if I have multiple sets of columns and rows like the data above? Is there any function that I can use to remove all "character"? I want only numbers to remain. :0

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question right. This solution should work for any number of columns and will always return numbers only(or NA if there weren't any). Please bring some example if that doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `mutate/across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), str_remove_all, "\\D+"))
#    q2_3 q2_4 q2_5
#1    1    2    3
#2    4    5    6
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(q2_3 = c("1A", "4D"), q2_4 = c("2B", "5E"), q2_5 = c("3C", 
"6F")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! btw I want to know if there is any function that can remove all characters. I want only numbers to remain!